# Does structopt support multi-contextual positional arguments?

Tags: rust, arguments, command-line-arguments, structopt

I'm trying to port `seq` to [`structopt`](https://docs.rs/crate/structopt/0.3.23), how should I support,

```
seq [OPTION]... LAST
seq [OPTION]... FIRST LAST
seq [OPTION]... FIRST INCREMENT LAST
```

Notice, that the position of the `LAST` argument changes in the argument list, for completeness it would be nice to know **BOTH**,

- Whether or not `structopt` supports varying positional arguments that are contextual and if so how?
- Whether or not `structopt` supports a position argument that is right-anchored and if so how?

Answer (score 0):

I don't believe it's possible, and when I try I get a generated error:

> Found positional argument which is not required with a lower index than a required positional argument

This means that the required arguments must come first. The best I think you can do is declare your last argument to be a `Vec<Strings>`

```
#[structopt(required=true)]
args: Vec<String>,
```